# Comments template only linking to one post

Tags: comment-form, plugin-jetpack, disqus

For some reason, the comments section at the bottom of each post (using single.php) seems to only be linked to a specific post on my blog, and only retrieves comments from that one post regardless of where the comments template is.

Someone commented on a post on the site, clearly talkig about the topic covered on one article, but when I went to moderate it, WP said it was posted on a completely unrelated article.

For example, if you scroll to the bottom of [this post](http://driver.dipstix.co.uk/2015/06/surviving-roads-driving-guide-to-italy/), and hover over the Comments RSS Feed link, it has a feed link for [this post](http://driver.dipstix.co.uk/2015/06/garage-price-vs-garage-reputation-poll/). Every post on my site that I've checked is linking back to that same article.

I've looked through the comments template and functions in the theme (called Fullby), but I can't find any reference to post IDs that would cause this.

I was originally using the default WordPress comments system after Disqus stopped working yesterday, but then installed Jetpack to see if it would solve this problem but it hasn't.

Comment: Post the relevant code please

Comment: possibly caused by some wrong code of the 'popular articles' section.